# Custom Button in XML

Tags: xml, android

I made this XML file to customize a button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="10dip" />

<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#0043E1"
    android:centerY="0.4"
    android:endColor="#6495ED"
    android:startColor="#6495ED"
    android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

What should I add to make the state focus and pressed please? A gradient color for the state pressed, and another for the state focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this tutorial on how do create the appropriate drawable-xml file to allow for different states of a button:

http://undertowsam.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/design-custom-background-and-button-for-android-using-xml/

Answer (score 4):

You need to write the selector for the button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_color" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focus_color" android:state_pressed="true">/item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_color"></item>
  </selector>
```

set this xml to the button back ground

Answer (score 2):

Create `button_selector.xml` inside `drawable` folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/image_normal" />
<item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/image_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/image_focused" />
</selector>
```

Then create two xml's one for pressed and other for focused as you have created already say `image_pressed.xml` and `image_focused.xml`